# Versioning with PHP namespaces and filesystem structure

Tags: php, namespaces, versioning

I was wondering if it's a good idea to use PHP's namespace / autoloading to version my code. The file system would be something like `/Class/<Package>/<version#>/<ClassName>`, and a PSR4 autoloader maps `new <OurVendorName>\<Package>\<version#>\<ClassName>()` to the appropriate directory. We also have a `/vendor/` directory for other vendors' packages we use.

My thoughts are to have a bunch of packages that run specific groups of logic, and a Slim router would use only the API package. The API package would essentially be a bunch of controllers pulling up the appropriate versions of the other packages and running them.

Doing so would allow the team to work independently on logic packages and only release new versions when backwards incompatible changes are being made. Other packages could migrate to new versions of their dependencies at their own pace without breaking anything. When we deprecate versions of packages, we can make the base object log the call stack upon instantiation to make refactoring easier to trace. Our API would also be versioned, so specific Slim routes could migrate to different versions of the API at their own pace.

I don't really see many flaws with this approach, but one possibility I considered was that it would be too much overhead. Between the filesystem holding multiple versions of every package and classes instantiating multiple versions of the same class would there be a potential performance hit? Also, would this level of granularity cause more headaches than it's worth? This is a project that is evolving very rapidly, so we need a system where we can quickly update our code without breaking anything.